# how to run countdown using NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, nstimer

I have developed an application in which I'm running a countdown timer. The timer fires a method every second. However, when the phone is in sleep mode, the timer becomes slow or even turns off.

I think I need to update the variables by calculating the time intervals using NSDate. Does someone knows how to do this?

BTW, our client has sent the following feedback:

> The timer problem appears to be caused
>   by the fact that the code assumes that
>   the timer notification messages are
>   delivered at exactly one second, but
>   aren't.  When the app is running but
>   the phone is in standby, it uses the
>   timer to update the countdown timer. 
>   But the timer comes in way more slowly
>   than one second, so the countdown
>   timer is off.  The app should be
>   reworked to always update the
>   countdown timer based on the current
>   time, and not count down based on the
>   timer messages themselves.  (In other
>   words, when the one second message
>   comes in, always assume that
>   additional time has gone by and
>   calculate the remaining time by
>   subtracting from the target time. This
>   is what happens when you restart the
>   app -- it figures out the target time
>   and the current time, subtracts one
>   from the other, and updates the
>   onscreen timer.  Well, this is how it
>   should always do it.)

If someone understand what exactly we need, please tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSTimers should never be used to actually keep time. They are dependent on the run loop and therefore can be interfered with by code that takes a long time to run.

You should stop the timer in `applicationWillResignActive:` and resume (actually, create another timer) in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

To calculate the dates you need something like:

```
    NSDate *startDate=[NSDate date];
    NSDate *endDate=[startDate addTimeInterval:someSeconds];
    NSTimeInterval secsElapsed;
    ...

-(void) timerDidFire:(NSTimer *) aTimer{
    NSDate *dateNow=[NSDate date];
    if ([[dateNow laterDate:endDate] isEqual:endDate]) {
        [aTimer invalidate];
        // end countdown
    }else {
        secsElapsed=[dateNow timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use epoch time. Epoch time is the number of seconds since Janury 1st, 1970.

When the program starts, save the current epoch time

```
double start = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

And then when you update your timer,

```
double running = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - start;
```

Will tell you how many seconds have passed since `start`.

Comment: [NSDate date] _is_ the current time.